# Bootstrap: Centering 2 forms next to eachother in Carousel Template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to center two forms sitting next to each other in twitter's bootstrap.
This is the template I am using given by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/carousel.html)

and this is the code I have so far. What it does is placing them on the top of each other.

```
<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
         <img class="header" src="img/header_bg.jpg" alt="">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">     
                <div class="span12">
                    <div class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" height="105px" width="96px"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- container logo -->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                          <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                          </label>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </form>

                    <form class="form-horizontal">
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="text" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <input type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="control-group">
                        <div class="controls">
                          <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox"> Remember me
                          </label>
                          <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign in</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                </form>

        </div>
        </div>



    </div> <!-- item active -->
  </div> <!-- carousel-inner -->
</div><!-- /.carousel -->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
 /* Carousel base class */
.carousel {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.carousel .container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 9;
}

.carousel-control {
  height: 80px;
  margin-top: 0;
  font-size: 120px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0;
  z-index: 10;
}

.carousel .item {
  height: 700px;
}
.carousel img.header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 700px;
}

.carousel-caption {
  background-color: transparent;
  position: static;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.carousel-caption h1,
.carousel-caption .lead {
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.25;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}
.carousel-caption .btn {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.logo {
    margin-left:-150px;
    float:left;
}
```

Can someone please help me out with this ? : ) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the forms side-by-side, we have to give them a 'float: left' CSS rule, like so:

```
.form-horizontal{
    float: left;   
}
```

Anyway, here's a JSFiddle with the new CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/4WwLX/1/

Comment: You're trying to get the forms side-by-side? It works fine in JSFiddle. Is there a webpage with a working example of what you want? Plus, next time, it'd be much more useful if you could tell me how it doesn't work

Comment: yeah but when I add the float or in JSFiddle it doesn't change

Comment: The JSFiddle already contains the appropriate CSS, if you want to update a change you have to click 'run' at the top of the screen. If you click on the JSFiddle link above, the forms appear side-by-side, at-least for me anyway - make sure that there's enough room for the forms to be displayed side-by-side